# Unable to import notebook from my desktop "MAC"

Tags: external-disk, desktop, import, onenote

I recently switched from a Windows PC to a MacBook Pro at my job. It's been extremely difficult to try and get my notebooks imported to onenote on my new mac. For someone reason, I don't see any feature that would allow me to import from my external drive/desktop. The only option I get is to import from onedrive but being that there are so many firewalls on the network, this makes it even more impossible. PLEASE HELP!!!

Answer (score 1):

Onenote doesn't work in a same way that you have in Windows PC. You have to upload your .onenote to Onedrive from your Windows PC and you can access them from your Mac.

So, "**Share**" your notebooks from OneNote for Windows to OneDrive — then OneNote for Mac will "see" them in OneDrive's Documents folder and sync them down to your Mac.